# Code design for handle funcs in go web app

Tags: go, web, design-patterns, request, httphandler

I'm learning go and ran into some design issues while developing web app. The app has main route "/" where user can submit a simple form. With those form values I am calling external API and unmarshaling response into some struct. Now from here I want to make another call based on retrieved values to another external API and I'm not sure what's the proper way of doing this. Here is a snippet for better understandment:

```golang
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", mainHandler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func mainHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //renders form template
    //makes post and retrieves data from api
    //here with retrieved data I want to make another call to different API,
    // but mainHandler would get too big and complex. I'm not sure how should I pass this data to
    // another handler or redirect to another handler with this data.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The handlers' semantics should be designed to match the desired HTTP behavior, regardless of the code complexity. If you want to handle a single client request by doing a bunch of stuff, that should be a single handler. If the handler becomes too complex, break it up. Handlers are just functions and can be broken up exactly like any other function - by extracting some part of it into another function and calling that new function. To take you pseudocode:

```
func mainHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := renderTemplate(w)
    if err != nil { ... }
    err, data := postToApi()
    if err != nil { ... }
    err, data2 := postToApi2(data)
    if err != nil { ... }
}
```

There's no reason for those functions to be handlers themselves or to get the client involved with a redirect. Just break up your logic the way you normally break up logic - it doesn't matter that it's an HTTP handler.

Answer (score -1):

Hi [golearner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11915351/golearner), in the **mainHandler** just render the form and make another handler kinda *"/formaction"* to handle the form, in that way you can easily organize your code.